# Geometric interpretation to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

For part (a) these are clearly two parallel lines so no points of intersection.
For part (b) this has one point of intersection because these two lines cross at exactly one point.
For parts (c) and (e) we have $z=0$ and $x=2y+1$ but what does this mean geometrically?
For part (d) there are no points of intersection so does that mean the three planes are parallel or the planes never cross anywhere?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=0$ and $x=2y+1$ gives the equation of a line; $x=2y+1$ is clearly a line in the $xy$-plane, and $z=0$ forces us to stay in this plane.

For d), you'll notice that all three planes are parallel, since the left hand sides are multiples of each other. (Two of the planes are in fact the same; namely those given by the first and second equations.)

Comment: So parts (c) and (e) have no points of intersection but rather a line of intersection?

Comment: Yes, the intersection is a line.

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$: two parallel  non-intersecting lines, (b) intesecting lines.

In the case of three planes (equations) when non two are parallel and no two are idendtical: Take $z=k$ and solve for %x, y$ punt these in the third equation.
One of the three things will happen:

(1) $k$ gets determined, the planes meet in a unique point form a an open tetrahedron.

(2) $k$ disappears giving a true statement e,g,, $6=6$ so many solutions, three planes meet in a line
like three pages of a book.

(3) $k$ disappears giving leaving a wrong statement $6=5$, so no solution, planes meeting an open prism.